# Is there this expression formally?

Tags: vectors

when I was having class today I got a doubt. Which one of these expressions exist formally? If not, why?

$$
\vec{V}=\vec{0} \,\, .
$$

Or

$$
\vec{V}=0 \,\, ,
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector can only be equal to another vector, so the right side had better mean the zero vector, not the scalar $0$.  However, notations differ: some people always use $\vec{0}$ to denote the zero vector, while others are not so fastidious and use $0$ for both the scalar $0$ and the zero vector.  It is generally clear from context which is meant.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question of notation. I would say that, almost always, when writing $\vec{V} = 0$, what is really meant is $\vec{V} = \vec{0}$, provided you are not working over some field which has elements $0$ and $\vec{0}$. Thus, if there is no element $0$ in your field, but an identity element $\vec{0}$, then *technically* (big butt face technically) $\vec{V} = 0$ is not a well-defined expression.

And as Robert's answer points out, their is a lot of variety (unfortunately too much, sometimes).

Comment: There is no such thing as a field without a $0$.